# Optimizar uso de switch-case statement

Tags: javascript

Tengo conocimientos muy básicos de JavaScript y estoy intentando optimizar una función switch que requiera casos infinitos.

Específicamente estoy creando un juego en mi tiempo libre mientras aprendo algo de programación básica y necesito crear un switch que no requiera de que escriba +1000 casos. Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
let pump = { 
level: 0,
water: 5,
flow: 0,
multiplier: 1,
workers: 0,
consumption: 0,

upgrade: function(){
    switch (this.level) {
        case 0:
            this.level = levelUp(this.level);
            break;
        case 1:
            mine.bronze -= 1;
            this.level = levelUp(this.level);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.level = levelUp(this.level);
            break;
    };
},
downgrade: function(){
    switch (this.level) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            this.level = levelDown(this.level);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.level = levelDown(this.level);
            break;
    };
},
addWorker: function () {
    switch (this.workers) {
        case 0:
            if (people < 0) {
                alert("No hay suficiente mano de obra.")
            } else {
                this.workers = levelUp(this.workers);
                people -= 1;
                this.flow = 1; }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (people < 1) {
                alert("No hay suficiente mano de obra.")
            } else {
                this.workers = levelUp(this.workers);
                people -= 1;
                this.flow = 2; }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (people < 1) {
                alert("No hay suficiente mano de obra.")
            } else {
                this.workers = levelUp(this.workers);
                people -= 1;
                this.flow = 3; }
            break;
        default:
            if (this.workers > 2) {this.workers = 2}
            break;
    }
},
removeWorker: function () {
    switch (this.workers) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            this.workers = levelDown(this.workers);
            people += 1;
            this.flow = 0;
            break; 
        case 2:
            this.workers = levelDown(this.workers);
            people += 1;
            this.flow = 1;
            break;
```

Obviamente el pump.level tendría un máximo, pero necesito generar los casos para los trabajadores (pump.workers) de manera ilimitada, ¿ideas?

Muchas gracias!!

EDITO: Añado código levelup y down por petición.

```
function levelUp(resource) {
    return resource += 1;   
};

function levelDown(resource) {
    return resource -= 1;   
};
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código correspondiente a levelUp y levelDown?

Comment: Agregado el código que pides @ricardo-dlc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he captado bien la idea, el código debería ser algo como lo siguiente:

```javascript
let pump = {
  level: 0,
  water: 5,
  flow: 0,
  multiplier: 1,
  workers: 0,
  consumption: 0,
  upgrade: function() {
    if (this.level >= 0) { // case 0... n:
      if (this.level === 1) { // case 1:
        mine.bronze -= 1;
      }

      this.level = levelUp(this.level);
    }
    return;
  },
  downgrade: function() {
    if (this.level === 0) { // case 0:
      return;
    }
    this.level = levelDown(this.level); // case 1... n:
    return;
  },
  addWorker: function() {
    if (this.workers === 0) { // case 0:
      if (people < 0) {
        alert('No hay suficiente mano de obra.');
        return;
      }
      this.workers = levelUp(this.workers);
      people -= 1;
      this.flow = this.workers + 1; // 0 + 1 = 1
      return;
    }

    if (this.workers >= 1 || this.level <= 2) { // case 1... 2:
      if (people < 1) {
        alert('No hay suficiente mano de obra.');
        return;
      }
      this.workers = levelUp(this.workers);
      people -= 1;
      // Se utiliza this.workes + 1 debido a que según tus casos (el switch es sobre this.workers) y lo que tienes ahora:
      // case 1: this.flow = 2 ó this.flow = this.workers + 1 <-- 1 + 1 = 2
      // case 2: this.flow = 3 ó this.flow = this.workers + 1 <-- 2 + 1 = 3
      // case n: this.flow = n + 1 ó this.flow = this.workers + 1 <-- n + 1 = n + 1
      this.flow = this.workers + 1;
      return;
    }

    // case default:
    // Supongo que aquí es donde quieres lo "ilimitado" puesto que aquí siempre que haya más de 2 workers
    // lo estás forzando a que sean dos, es decir, los estás desapareciendo "mágicamente" por lo que para esto
    // bastaría con eliminar este if y eliminar el límite superior del if que está inmediatamente arriba de este comentario
    if (this.workers > 2) {
      this.workers = 2
    }
    return;
  },
  removeWorker: function () {
    if (this.workers <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    // case 1... n:
    // Caso similar a addWorkers -> this.flow = this.workers - 1
    // this.flow = n - 1 -> this.workers - 1 -> n - 1
    this.flow = this.workers - 1;
    this.workers = levelDown(this.workers);
    people += 1;
    return;
  }
}
```

Hice algunas observaciones, puedes "optimizarlo" aún más eliminando las acotaciones de rango en `addWorkers` para hacerlo "ilimitado" o incrementar el rango máximo que tiene (ahora solo 2);

Comment: Como he dicho, es un projecto que hago en mi tiempo libre, en cuanto pueda miro el codigo y lo pruevo, creo que mas o menos lo entiendo. Si tengo alguna duda volveré a responderte. De momento lo marco como resuelto, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Claro, cualquier duda estamos en contacto